# Does BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER only work on incoming packets?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, ebpf

I have wrote a simple BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER used for tracing HTTP messages then I want to know where the socket filter play its function.

After reading some blogs I knew the following kernel code calls socket filter eventually:

```c
int sock_queue_rcv_skb(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    int err;

    err = sk_filter(sk, skb);
    if (err)
        return err;

    return __sock_queue_rcv_skb(sk, skb);
}
```

As I know, the function `sock_queue_rcv_skb` only works on receiving packets, so it seems socket filter only could handle incoming packets. But my socket filter can handle both egress and ingress packets it sounds contradictory to theoretical knowledge.

I am not familiar with kernel network stack hope someone help figure out these questions. Thanks in advance